# Can i open an android app using just the package name in a website?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, package

I want to know if its possible to make a button in html that can launch any app (assuming the user has it installed) with the package name, i dont *think* its possible but someone out there might know how.

`document.location.href = 'intent:#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=app_package;end;';`

just goes to the google play app showing the app_package app

ive tried one or two other things but there hasnt been anything else that works

Deep linking assumes that the app *has* a deep link in the first place, so that won't work; which is why I want to be able to launch any app with the package name.

Answer (score 0):

It is done via a link, not a package but if you want this should be search inside google play i thing so you can use api for search via package.
like this

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=yourpackage

Comment: This only opens to the app on the Google play page, it does open the app itself

Answer (score -1):

yes by using this code

Button launchButton = findViewById(R.id.launchButton);

launchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
String packageName = "exampleapp"; // replace with the package name of the target app

```
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the target app is not installed
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

});

Comment: This is Android source code. The question is for a button on a Web site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).